# Not able to render eye gaze animation on sheepit

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, makehuman, sheepit

[image]

First image is the sheepit rendered image

[image]

Second I have rendered on my machine, macbook pro
I have created this human modal in makehuman and imported as .mhx2.

for setting the animation 
I key the head before and after rotation. This works fine on my machine, eyes rotation follow the head, but on sheepit eyes are at the same place and only head is moving.

Also, I am using mhx rig. This provides an option "gazefollowshead" under section "mhx control". when set it to 0 it renders in the same way as sheepit does. I am guessing this is the issue, not sure though.

please help me, I have completed the whole animation and now I am not able to render it.

[image]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.

Comment: @cegaton Thanks a lot for your comment, I have updated my question with more information. If it is not enough pls let me know, thanks again. Sorry for the inconvenience I am new to it.

Comment: Are the eyes an object that rotates or an animated texture? Do you have any cached files that are not copied over to the render farm? Are all of the elements used on the local computer available on the render farm?

Comment: 1.) Using object type eyes. 2.)  I have packed all the files in .blend, does that ensure all the cache object copied?. 3.) On uploading .blender file on sheepit it doesn't show any warning. thanks again for your replies.